# Rundeck 4.0.0 - Remote node command execution using ssh

Tags: rundeck

I am having an issue with the most basic of Rundeck functions - namely, running a command over ssh on a remote node. I have generated a rsa key and added it via the `Key Storage` function. I have also created a yaml file for node definitions:

```
root@rundeck:/var/lib/rundeck# cat nodes.yml

mynode:
  nodename: mynode
  hostname: mynode
  description: 'Some description'
  ssh-authentication: privateKey            # added - unsure if really required
  ssh-keypath: /var/lib/rundeck/.ssh/id_rsa # added - unsure if really required
  username: rundeck
  osFamily: linux
```

The node is showing up correctly and command line ssh works just fine:

```
root@rundeck:/var/lib/rundeck/.ssh# ssh -i id_rsa rundeck@mynode date
Mon Apr  4 16:19:33 UTC 2022
```

The project settings are as below:

```
#Mon Apr 04 16:23:36 UTC 2022
#edit below
project.description=someproject
project.disable.executions=false
project.disable.schedule=false
project.execution.history.cleanup.batch=500
project.execution.history.cleanup.enabled=false
project.execution.history.cleanup.retention.days=60
project.execution.history.cleanup.retention.minimum=50
project.execution.history.cleanup.schedule=0 0 0 1/1 * ? *
project.jobs.gui.groupExpandLevel=1
project.label=somelabel
project.name=someproject
project.nodeCache.enabled=true
project.nodeCache.firstLoadSynch=true
project.output.allowUnsanitized=false
project.ssh-authentication=privateKey
project.ssh-command-timeout=0
project.ssh-connect-timeout=0
project.ssh-key-storage-path=keys/project/someproject/rundeck_id_rsa
resources.source.1.config.file=/var/lib/rundeck/nodes.yml
resources.source.1.config.format=resourceyaml
resources.source.1.config.requireFileExists=true
resources.source.1.config.writeable=true
resources.source.1.type=file
service.FileCopier.default.provider=jsch-scp
service.NodeExecutor.default.provider=jsch-ssh
```

Yet, when I try and run a `Command` from the UI, it fails:

```
Failed: SSHProtocolFailure: invalid privatekey: [B@7d7d0b2d
```

What am I doing incorrectly, and how do I successfully run a command over ssh on a remote node?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your node definition needs the `ssh-key-storage-path` attribute pointing to the Rundeck user private key (created before on Rundeck Key Storage), also, the `osFamily` attribute must be set as `unix` (not `linux`, Rundeck only admits two values there: `unix` and `windows`).

To add an SSH node follow these steps:

1. If you're using a WAR-based installation execute: `ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096`. That generates two keys (private and public) on the user `.ssh` directory (the user that launches Rundeck). If you're using an RPM/DEB installation these keys are already created on the `/var/lib/rundeck` path.
2. Go to the remote SSH node (the account that you want to connect from Rundeck), then add the Rundeck server user public key to the `authorized_keys` file. Then you can test that connection with `ssh user@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` from the Rundeck server user account.
3. Launch Rundeck and then add to the Rundeck keys storage the `rundeck` user private key (remember to include the first and the last line "`-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`" and "`-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`") in my case I use this path `keys/rundeck`.
4. Create a new Project and then create the `resources.xml` file with remote node information. To generate that file just go to Project Settings > Edit Nodes > Click on the "Configure Nodes" button > Click on "Add Sources +" > Select "+ File" option > in the "Format" field select `resourcexml` and fill the path in "File Path" field (put the file name at the end, usually "resources.xml", also, select "Generate", "Include Server Node" and "Writeable" checkboxes and click on the "Save" button.
5. Now you can edit that file including the remote node, which in my case is "node00" (a Vagrant test image),  on the `key-storage-path` attribute I used the same path created in step 3:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project>
  <node name="hyperion" description="Rundeck server node" tags="" hostname="hyperion" osArch="amd64" osFamily="unix" osName="Linux" osVersion="4.15.0-66-generic" username="ruser"/>
  <node name="node00" description="Node 00" tags="" hostname="192.168.33.20" osArch="amd64" osFamily="unix" osName="Linux" osVersion="3.10.0-1062.4.1.el7.x86_64" username="vagrant" ssh-key-storage-path="keys/rundeck"/>
</project>
```

5. On Rundeck GUI go to the sidebar and check your nodes on the "Nodes" section. [Check](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/51376003/81188340-33287a80-8f83-11ea-978d-27b9c3bd89ad.png).
6. Go to "Commands" (sidebar) and put the SSH remote node name as a filter and launch any command like [this](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/51376003/81186655-0c694480-8f81-11ea-8d79-9e06be6378c1.png).

You can follow an entire guide [here](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/learning/howto/ssh-on-linux-nodes.html#using-ssh-on-linux-unix-nodes).

Alternatively, you can re-generate the key pairs with the following command: `ssh-keygen -p -f /var/lib/rundeck/.ssh/id_rsa -m pem`.

Comment: I am still struggling with this. I can't see much in your answer that I haven't done. I have changed the node source to xml, changed osFamily back to "unix", added ssh-key-storage-path to "keys/rundeck" (after re-uploading a private key to that path):
<node name="mynode" description="something" tags="k8s" hostname="mynode" osArch="amd64" osFamily="unix" osName="Linux" username="rundeck" ssh-key-storage-path="keys/rundeck"/>
It still fails with "invalid private key [B@1716200b", yet works at the command line:
su - rundeck -s /bin/bash -c "ssh -i .ssh/id_rsa rundeck@mynode date"

Comment: Could you try re-generating the keys in this way? https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/issues/6022#issuecomment-1013908189 (also described here https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/issues/4813#issuecomment-492358649)

Comment: Yep, that's it. What a nasty gotcha :sadface: 
"ssh-keygen -f /var/lib/rundeck/.ssh/id_rsa -m pem"
Perhaps worthy of a documentation update? Thank you very much for the assistance.

Answer (score 0):

The `keystorage` save the `private-key` with `crlf` and this was the issue I recognize with version `4.2.1`.

Do a dirty fix for `ssh-exec.sh`:

```
echo "$RD_CONFIG_SSH_KEY_STORAGE_PATH" > "$SSH_KEY_STORAGE_PATH"
```

**insert these lines:**

```
sed -i 's/\r$//' "$SSH_KEY_STORAGE_PATH"

SSHOPTS="$SSHOPTS -i $SSH_KEY_STORAGE_PATH"
```