# How to read public and private keys from key storage inside a job?

Tags: rundeck

I have three differents keys inside my Key Storage : private, public, and password.
When editing a job and adding a parameter ("option") and marks it as secure, I can navigate through the key storage to select the password key.

But I can't see nor use the private and public keys.
Writing the full path doesn't work as Rundeck says on job execution that the key "couldn't be read", even if the path is the same shown on key storage page.

Can you tell me how is it possible to add these keys in my job ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By design and for security reasons isn't possible to use private/public keys on options. Alternatively, you can create a [plugin](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/developer/12-option-values-plugins.html#option-values-plugins) to retrieve those keys. [Here](https://groups.google.com/g/rundeck-discuss/c/6kJrh1evfVM/m/5vFGWwl-AAAJ) you can see an example to get keys using a workflow step custom plugin.

[Here](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/developer/) a general plugin development guide. And [here](https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/tree/main/examples) are some examples.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer and several links.
It leads to another question then : what is the purpose of these public/private key ?
For SSH only ?
Why making the confusion by using them the same way than password, and why there is nothing in the documentation ?

Comment: Yeah, it's only for model source, for example using the `ssh-key-storage-path` in any SSH node entry on the `resources.xml` /`resources.yaml` model source file, take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71740876/10426011