# Using Rundeck to edit a file on remote host

Tags: file, editor, rundeck

Is there a way to edit a file on remote host using Rundeck? Like a cronjob, config file etc.

Couldn't find any concrete way. Only thing that works is copy the file on local host, edit it and then push it back to remote host. It is more manual than expected.

Answer (score 0):

You can work directly on the remote node.

1. Configure your remote node with the right user following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71740876/10426011).
2. Edit the file directly using some tool like `jq` or `sed`.
3. Save it.

Comment: Thanks for answering. But I do not want to login on production host and want to control through a tool like Rundeck remotely, similar to remote execution of commands. Its only for the purpose of editing cronjobs or config file I need to edit something on production host. So was looking for someway we can have in Rundeck?

Comment: Rundeck needs remote nodes to work, in your specific case, your approach does the trick.